# Synchronization between silverlight datagrid and its bound datasource

Tags: silverlight, binding, datagrid, synchronization

In Silverlight 4, I've bound a datagrid to an ObservableCollection datasource.

Here is the xaml code for the interface:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="179" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="667,10,0,0" Name="dgASupprimer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="334" DataContext="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False, Mode=OneWay}" LoadingRow="dgASupprimer_LoadingRow" />
    <Button Content="ASupprimer" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="905,205,0,0" Name="bASupprimer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="bASupprimer_Click" />
```

And the one for initializing the datasource:

```
public class fmLabClass
    {
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public fmLabClass(string nom, int age) { Age = age; Nom = nom; }
    }
    System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<fmLabClass> fmLabObservableCollection = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<fmLabClass>() { 
            new fmLabClass("Person1",34),
            new fmLabClass("Person2",36),
            new fmLabClass("Person3",45)
        };
```

When I press the bASupprimer button, I wish to change a value of an attribute on the object, and get in return the datagrid reevaluated.

```
private void bASupprimer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgASupprimer.SelectedIndex = 2;
        ((fmLabClass)(dgASupprimer.SelectedItem)).Age++;
    }
```

The current result is that the datagrid doesn’t refresh automatically. How can I do that?

Thx

Comment: +1 for providing your source (so few do) :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your properties are notify properties if you want them to broadcast changes. Full required changes shown below. This is a common pattern you will need to know about in Silverlight if you want binding to work. There are code snippets about for properties like these (to save typing).

```
    public class fmLabClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _Nom;
        public string Nom 
        { 
            get {return _Nom;} 
            set
            {
                if (_Nom != value)
                {
                    _Nom = Value; 
                    OnPropertyChanged("Nom");
                }
            }
        }

        private int _Age;
        public int Age
        { 
            get {return _Age;} 
            set
            {
                if (_Age!= value)
                {
                    _Age= Value; 
                    OnPropertyChanged("Age");
                }
            }
        }

        public fmLabClass(string nom, int age) { Age = age; Nom = nom; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                 PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fmLabClass needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order to tell the UI that there is a change in your object.

Comment: Thanks Xin, that gave me a good start to find the final answer. I add the following link on msdn that explains more the INotifyPropertyChanged approach: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also watch this sample chapter on Databinding from Billy Hollis:

http://s3.amazonnaws.com/dnrtv/dnrtv_0175.wmv

Not in French though.